# Dynamic UI in android: How to add text fields and edit texts in proper position?

Tags: android, user-interface

I wish to create a UI which, initially, has a button, which when clicked, adds a TextView and EditText (placed in a separate XML file for inflating) at the top of the screen, while the button shifts to below the EditText. Clicking the button again adds another TextView and EditText below the previous ones and the button shifts below again (kind of like how we add a new number to a contact in android by pressing the small green '+' icon).

I have been able to inflate the TextView and EditView from the program, but the position of all the views is not correct: I get the TextView and EditText, but the button disappears when clicked. I would appreciate some sample code which shows how to do something like what I described.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically having some fun with LayoutParams.

To make it easier, you should go ahead and create several items similar to what you want on the eclipse visual developing area for the xml layouts. This will help you get a better understanding of the properties required to make a certain appearance.

With these properties in mind, you can go ahead and translate them into code that will add it dynamically.

This is essentially the basic approach:
1. Go to your xml layout and add some text fields and or edit texts to the preferences you like as if you were the cellphone and the user is pressing the buttons required to add these views dynamically.

1. Look at the properties you adjusted to get that specific look
2. This is the basic coding approach to all this:

**Here I will show you how to add a TextView to a ViewGroup**

```
LayoutParams.LAYOUT_TYPE_HOLDING_THE_VIEW_YOU_WILL_ADD lp = 
new LayoutParams.LAYOUT_TYPE_HOLDING_THE_VIEW_YOU_WILL_ADD
(LayoutParams.LAYOUT_TYPE_HOLDING_THE_VIEW_YOU_WILL_ADD.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.LAYOUT_TYPE_HOLDING_THE_VIEW_YOU_WILL_ADD.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.gravity = Gravity.Right;
lp.weight = 1f;

//And so on
TextView tv = new TextView(Context);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

LAYOUT_HOLDING_THE_VIEW.add(tv);

//NOTES:
//Sometimes the program may not update these changes, so just to be safe, you can go    ahead and call this method:

LAYOUT_HOLDING_THE_VIEW.invalidate(); once you are done adding these fields.
```

So that should do the trick most of the time;

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code once which is working fine.

```
final LinearLayout _layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.totalview);
        final LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)inflator.inflate(R.layout.add_view, null);
                _layout.addView(v,0);
            }
        });
```